# Email server multiple domain with different IPs

Tags: domain-name-system, email, postfix

I have 2 domains:

1. `ex1.example` with IP `192.0.2.1`
2. `ex2.example` with IP `203.0.113.2`

On `ex1.example` I installed `postfix` and `dovecot` with support working on multiple domains (MariaDB with tables and other stuff). Now I want to receive email for the following email addresses:

- `support@ex1.example`
- `postmaster@ex1.example`
- `support@ex2.example`
- `postmaster@ex2.example`

With `postmaster@ex1.example` and `support@ex1.example` everything okay, I can receive emails, but when I try to send email to `support@ex2.example` or `postmaster@ex2.example` - nothing happens.

DNS zone settings for domain ex1.com:

- A Record @ `192.0.2.1`
- A Record mail `192.0.2.1`
- A Record www `192.0.2.1`
- MX Record `ex1.example` `mail.ex1.example.`
- MX Record `mail.ex1.example` `ex1.example.`

DNS zone settings for domain ex2.com:

- A Record @ `203.0.113.2`
- A Record mail `192.0.2.1`
- MX Record `ex2.example` `mail.ex1.example.`

When I try to send an email to `support@mail.ex2.example` I got an error in maillot:

```
Mar 25 22:47:02 ex1 postfix/smtpd[6000]: NOQUEUE: reject: RCPT from: 454 4.7.1 <support@mail.ex2.example>: Relay access denied; from=<user@domain.localdomain> to=<support@mail.ex2.example> proto=ESMTP helo=<user.localdomain>
```

Comment: You need to configure Postfix too.

Comment: @MichaelHampton postfix configured for both domains

Comment: Shouldn't you send the mail to `support@ex2.com`? I think that is how your DNS is configured. You should add a record `mail.ex2.com IN NS mail.ex1.com` or `mail.ex2.com IN NS ex1.com`, if you want to send mails to domain `mail.ex2.com`. Now your only record for mail.ex2.com is an A record. Relaying for `ex2.com` is not entered.

Comment: @nobody without MX entries at all? For domain ex2.com only `NS record` (or `A record`?) like `mail.ex2.com IN NS mail.ex1.com`? and I can send email to `support@ex2.com` or `support@mail.ex2.com`?

Comment: Sorry, I meant `MX`, not `NS`, and numbers for `MX` records priorities are missing. You will know which numbers you want to put in.

Comment: @nobody can you please write all zones for ex1.com and ex2.com as answer? I don't understand what records should be indeed.

Answer (score 1):

you should make your mail server to be mail server for both domains. The configuration you have now, says that mails for domain `ex2.example` are handled by mail server `mail.ex1.example`. The line you wrote tells me that you have only defined mail for domain `ex2.example` and not `mail.ex2.example`.

- MX Record `ex2.example` `mail.ex1.example.`

You do not have an entry for domain `mail.ex2.example`. I think you should add an entry for `mail.ex2.example` domain:

```
mail.ex2.example. IN MX 10 mail.ex1.example.
```

You also say that mails for

- `support@ex1.example`
- `postmaster@ex1.example`
- `support@ex2.example`
- `postmaster@ex2.example`

should work. However, than you complain that mail `support@mail.ex2.example` does not work, which is not on the list. I believe `support@ex2.example` should work according to configuration you have provided. When you add the line I suggest, I think also `support@mail.ex2.example` should work, too.

Comment: actually you are wrong understand me. in my current configuration email: `support@ex1.com`, `postmaster@ex1.com` works perfectly, but `support@ex2.com`, `postmaster@ex2.com` DOES NOT work at all.

Comment: I would suggest to go through your logs and find out where and why the mail is stopped. It is either wrong DNS or mail server configuration. According to your description I suspected that DNS is wrong, because your question shows that you have not configured it for `mail.ex2.com` domain. It may be anything. Take a look here for instructions how to configure MX records http://mirror.thelifeofkenneth.com/sites/qt.vidyagam.es/library/Networking/DNS%20and%20BIND,%205th%20Edition/DNS%20and%20BIND,%205th%20Edition%20-%20Cricket%20Liu%20&%20Paul%20Albitz.pdf